# How/Why does resampling from "any" distribution lead to a normal distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution, monte-carlo, central-limit-theorem, resampling

I was performing some Monte-Carlos on historical data and irrespective of the distribution of the data I would always get a normal distribution owing to resampling with replacement. That made it easy for me to predict with 95% confidence what the expected value of that 'variable' would be.

So far so good and so cool! No matter what the historical distribution of the variable looked like, resampling and estimating future probability of occurrence always seemed to follow a normal distribution. Now, normal distribution is not so normal in practice. So what's the phenomenon that leads to a normal distribution? Is there a mathematical proof for it? I'm sure it has something to do with the central limit theorem but I'm quite baffled and intrigued at the beauty of producing a normal distribution when resampling with replacement.

I may be incorrect but is this true in general? Irrespective of my historical distribution (whether, beta, poisson, binomial, random etc.) I keep getting a normal distribution on resampling. Any help on the mathematics underpinning this phenomenon would be helpful.

Comment: What, specifically, were you doing with your resampled sample?  For example, were you calculating a sample mean, then looking at the distribution of that across all the resamples?

Comment: To see what @jbowman is leading to, Nupul, take a minute to do a Monte-Carlo simulation of the *product* of the data values.  Unless you have unusual data, the resulting distribution won't be anywhere near normal :-).

Comment: How are you "estimating future probability of occurrence" ? Occurrence of what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal distribution comes up as the approximate distribution for averages and weighted averages.  If you have a large sample from some distribution sampling with replacement from this large sample should only give back the original distribution.  So if you did not start with a normal distribution you shouldn't be getting one back.

Answer (score 2):

I will anticipate your answer to @jbowman's comment and presume you were calculating a sample mean or total or something similar when you talk about your 'variable'.

You have stumbled on the ["central limit theorem"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) - one of the most fundamental elements of statistical theory and practice - and it has indeed been proven.  I'd certainly endorse your interest in familiarising yourself with it and other statistical inference fundamentals, given the techniques you are using and problems you seem to be applying them to.

Happy learning!